# What are some good starter books to learn how to brew beer?

Tags: beginner

I'm looking for well known and well respected authors.  Something that has an A-Z format, if you will, and history of home brewing or something of the like.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Brewing Classic Styles is a recommended Recipe Book. Buy this book when you have read the recommended materials below.

Comment: Podcasts are also a great source of information. Basic Brewing Radio and The Jamil Show should be listened to from the first episode. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joy of Homebrewing by Charlie Papazian. This is the only intro you'll need to successfully inoculate yourself into the beer making culture. Relax, don't worry, and have a homebrew!

Comment: This helped me a lot when i started, I highly recommend reading it. 
it gives the basics, from starting with extract, to beginning with all grain setup.

Answer (score 8):

How to Brew: Everything You Need To Know To Brew Beer Right The First Time by John J. Palmer.

Comment: How to brew covers the very basics to quite advanced topics (which you can skip on the first read). Highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to buy a physical book, John Palmer has a website which is full of info, including step-by-step guides for different brewing techniques, as well as a lot of technical detail:

http://www.howtobrew.com/sitemap.html

Personally I have read, and re-read, "Brew Your Own British Real Ale" by Graham Wheeler. Whilst it has a focus on British styles, including recipe of many well- known ales, the guides are very useful for brewing ale in general. The writing is thorough, but concise, with a no-nonsense approach, which I personally appreciate. It allowed me to take the plunge from extract based ales to all grain.

Comment: I'd recommend you buy the book.  The website is the first edition.  The 3rd is now in print and John is working on the 4th.  There's been a lot of corrections and new info since the online version.

Answer (score 0):

I still really like Home Brew Beer by Greg Hughes. There is a recipe for nearly every style in there as well.